# Calling a function once in a range

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I have an assignment and couldn't figure out the true solution.

```
def triple(n):    #multiplies number with 3
    return (n*3)
def square(n):
    return (n**2)   #takes second power of number

for i in range(1,11):
    if triple(i) > square(i):
        print((f"triple({i})=={triple(i)} square({i})=={square(i)}"))
```

```
triple(1)==3 square(1)==1
triple(2)==6 square(2)==4
```

1. I should stop the iteration when the square of a value is larger than the triple of the value, without printing anything in the last iteration.
2. And both functions triple and square are must called exactly once per iteration.

other things i tried

```
    ls =[f"triple({i})=={triple(i)} square({i})=={square(i)}" for i in range(1,11) if triple(i) > square(i)]
    for i in ls:
        print(i)
```

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    x = triple(i)
    y = square(i)
    if x > y:  #when i put x>=y its acceps the numberof calling squares but not triple
        print(f"triple({i})=={x} square({i})=={y}")
```

There is a test that checks my answers and it says "wrong number of printed lines", I asked someone from course they just told me that ı should store the values getting from each functions into a variable. And these are what I tried to do what they said

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You never check for the first condition you mention. It should be something like `if x < y: break`

Comment: Your `if` just decides whether or not to print; there is *nothing* in this code to even attempt to stop the loop before it exhausts the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    x = triple(i)
    y = square(i)
    if x >= y:  
        print(f"triple({i})=={x} square({i})=={y}")
    else:
        break
```

this one solved, I give up after several times of trying to breaking the loop. My foolnes

Thanks for helping @UnholySheep and @Vaibhav Khandelwal. But Vaibhav on that bunch of code test didnt accept, it was counting the if statemnts either

Comment: Why `elif y > x` and not just `else`?

Comment: You're right :D I didn't think of that at, that  moment

Answer (score 0):

You need to put another condition for square> triple and when that matches yo can come out of the loop through **break**

```
def triple(n):    #multiplies number with 3
    return (n*3)
def square(n):
    return (n**2)   #takes second power of number

for i in range(1,11):
    if triple(i) > square(i):
        print((f"triple({i})=={triple(i)} square({i})=={square(i)}"))
    elif triple(i) < square(i):
        break
```